# Silverlight: Canvas overflows

Tags: silverlight, canvas, overflow, stackpanel, clipping

I have created a Canvas, and within it I placed a StackPanel. The StackPanel is horizontal, and it accepts a list of thumbnailed images. The Canvas has a fixed size. When I put more thumbnails than the Canvas width can hold, the StackPanel is supposed to overflow from the Canvas, so I can move it to center the current thumbnail.

Everything works correctly, only, the StackPanel's overflow is visible! Is there a way to hide it? Or is the entire approach wrong?

Here is a screenshot. The canvas is the red box. The stackpanel is blue semi-transparent.

http://www.netpalantir.it/static/sl_canvas_overflows.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the Canvas has fixed size, you can use [clipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip(VS.95).aspx). Basically you have to do:

```
<Canvas Width="400" Height="300">
    <Canvas.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 400, 300"/>
    </Canvas.Clip>
    <!-- your StackPanel here -->
</Canvas>
```

Here are few useful posts on the topic:

[Clipping in Silverlight](http://timrmiller.com/Blog/post/Clipping-in-Silverlight.aspx)

[Cropping or Clipping in Silverlight](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/clipSl11032008205938PM/clipSl.aspx)